# How to setup Github codespaces with custom Docker setup?

Tags: visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-devcontainer, codespaces, github-codespaces

My project consists out of two components.

```
┌────────────────┐
│ Docker compose │http  ┌─────────┐
│ (http server,  ├─────►│         │
│  sql server    │      │ Go app  │
│  etc.)         │      │         │
└────────────────┘      └─────────┘
     ▲
     │ incoming http
```

1. A docker compose file containing multiple services (**http-server**, sql, auth server, etc.). Secondly
2. A Go app with my custom app logic that the **http-server** directs certain queries too.

In VScode I usually start up the Docker compose in a Terminal to run all services, and then run the Go app in debug as it contains app logic and receives the http requests that the http-server forwards.

Both components can be build and deployed as a whole via `./Dockerfile`.

I now want to run all of this into GitHub Codespaces but I am not sure how to organize my Docker files. Since Go isn't installed on the Github Codespaces machines, do I need a second `Dockerfile` in which my Codespace environment runs in like `Dockerfile.codespace`? Or do I need a Docker compose file instead that collects all components/services including Go?